# MySQL not showing value when using <= condition

Tags: mysql

i have records in my database like this
*just example

| id | Name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jono | 2020-03-21 12:20:00 |
| 2 | Abi | 2020-03-25 12:20:00 |
| 3 | Iko | 2020-03-30 12:20:00 |

then i have simple query like this 
 `` SELECT * FROM `transaksi` WHERE `created_at` >= '2020-03-21' AND `created_at` <= '2020-03-30' `` 
but that query only show id no 1 and 2 which is the date is < 2020-03-30 
so my question is 
**why the third data which is still in range is not showing?** 
i have try something like this too
 `` SELECT * FROM `transaksi` WHERE `created_at` >= DATE('2020-03-21') AND `created_at` <= DATE('2020-03-30') `` 
but still have same issue
any sugestion?
thanks

Comment: It is the time element of 2020-03-30 12:20:00  which is 12 hours and 20 minutes after 2020-03-30 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the logical query you want here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM transaksi
WHERE created_at >= '2020-03-21' AND created_at < '2020-04-01';
```

To explain what the above is actually saying, let's rewrite it using timestamp literals, with full `H:M:S` components:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM transaksi
WHERE created_at >= '2020-03-21 00:00:00' AND created_at < '2020-04-01 00:00:00';
```

Both of these queries will retain any record having a created date on or after midnight of 21-March-2020 *and* strictly *before* midnight of 1st-April-2020.  The right side condition then includes the entire day of 31-March-2020.

Comment: so what should i do is +1 day for last date statement or using full with time `H:M:S` ? @tim

Comment: I have explained your problem clearly as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

You have to apply mysql **[DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)** function on *created_at* column to get date only without time.

```
SELECT *
FROM `transaksi`
WHERE DATE(`created_at`) >= '2020-03-21'
  AND DATE(`created_at`) <= '2020-03-30'
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ee6b/1)**

Comment: Yes, that would work, but prevents the usage of an index on `created_at`. So the preferred solution should be to check the upper bound excluded with one day ahead, like the first query in Tim Biegeleisen's answer.

Comment: And calling functions unnecessarily, twice in each row, can't be justified against simply moving the upper date to the next day.